# Copying all files inside subdirectories and renaming instead of overwriting

Tags: linux, find, cp

I have a number of images inside subdirectories of another directory which I'd like to copy to one single directory so all the images are in one place.

After a bit of searching, I found and then modified some things to create this command:

```
find . -name "z*.jpg" -exec cp '{}' ~/Extracted/ \;
```

This seemingly worked, however I found that images with the same name would be overwritten, so then I did this:

```
find . -name "z*.jpg" -exec cp -n '{}' ~/Extracted/ \;
```

But now images with the same name are simply ignored.

Is there anyway I could do this so every image is copied over and images with the same name are renamed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[GNU `cp(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/cp.1.html) has a backup option:

```
cp --backup SOURCE [SOURCE...] [DESTINATION]
```

This has the following effects which can be controlled with other options as described in the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/cp.1.html) of `cp(1)`:

> ```
> --backup[=CONTROL]
>           make a backup of each existing destination file
>
> -b     like --backup but does not accept an argument
>
> -S, --suffix=SUFFIX
>           override the usual backup suffix
> ```
>
> The backup suffix is `~`, unless set with `--suffix` or
>   `SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX`. The version control method may be  selected 
>   via the `--backup` option or through the `VERSION_CONTROL` environment
>   variable. Here are the values:
>
> - `none`, `off`: never make backups (even if `--backup` is given)
> - `numbered`, `t`: make numbered backups
> - `existing`, `nil`: numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
> - `simple`, `never`: always make simple backups

## Example

```
cp --backup=existing --suffix=.orig ~/Music/* ~/Videos
```

This will copy all files in `~/Music` to `~/Videos`. If a file of the same name exists at the destination, it is renamed by appending `.orig` to its name as a backup. If a file with the same name as the backup exists, the backup is instead renamed by appending `.1` and, if that exists as well, `.2` and so forth. Only then is the source file copied to the destination.

If you want to copy files in subdirectories recursively use `-R`:

```
cp -R --backup=existing --suffix=.orig ~/Music ~/Videos
```

Comment: While the other answer solved my problem, this solution is much easier to implement. This may be useful in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is actually to find a `cp` variant that creates the target file under a different name if it already exists. I'm not aware of a tool that does so, however, it's not hard to implement yourself:

```sh
cp -vn "$1" "$2"/ || cp -vn "$1" "$2"/"${1##*/}"~"$(md5sum "$1" | cut -f1 -d' ')"
```

This script calls `cp` again in case it fails, appending the checksum to the filename. Flaw: If a third file with the same name shows up, it will overwrite the second file **if they are identical**.

Given that the above script is called `saveCopy` and stored in the parent working directory, the following works:

```
$ find . -name 'z*.jpg' -exec ./saveCopy {} /tmp/Extracted/ \;
./a/z1.jpg -> /tmp/Extracted/z1.jpg
./a/z2.jpg -> /tmp/Extracted/z2.jpg
./a/z3.jpg -> /tmp/Extracted/z3.jpg
/tmp/Extracted/z3.jpg not overwritten
./b/z3.jpg -> /tmp/Extracted//z3.jpg~d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
./b/z4.jpg -> /tmp/Extracted/z4.jpg
```

Be aware that the script only works for a single input file and if the target is a directory! It can certainly be improved ;-)

Comment: Nice, +1. Why would it be a flaw to overwrite _identical_ files?

Comment: @terdon the flaw is actually more that you still end up with 2 copies of an identical file, because the first copy doesn't have the hash attached. It's not consistent. However, I just wanted to keep the example small, if one wants to use something like this on a regular basis one should think of a slightly more sophisticated solution.

Comment: You can make it more consistent just omitting copying the original filename, using only the code after ||: cp -vn "$1" "$2"/"${1##*/}"~"$(md5sum "$1" | cut -f1 -d' ')" - the problem however is that the file extension gets messed up with the md5sum

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a bug in the homebrew version of GNU cp, running on Catalina, that causes it to hang when it is copying into a directory with a very large number (several thousand) of files and renaming files with --backup. Issue was resolved by reducing the number of files in the target directory. E.g., with 1000 files, it worked as expected.

Comment: This question is about Linux in general and not Homebrew specific installs.